# Recommended authentication flow on MDM managed iOS devices

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak

We're building an iOS native app together with two web apps. For identiy/access management we are using Keycloak (supports OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0).

The iOS apps are installed on MDM managed devices. Only our apps are installed.

I learnt that the current best practice for implementing authentication/authorization is to use OpenId Connect and a browser based flow through an external user agent:

- http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2016-May/007259.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.txt
- https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/

using one of these libraries:

- https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS
- https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-ios-oauth2

Is it also recommended for MDM managed iOS devices (with no "evil" third party apps, just our own stuff) to implement a browser based flow? Or is it safe in this case to implement a native login flow (user enters credentials directly into the app)?

I am worried about the user experience... That switch between our app and the browser does not look very smooth...

Comment: I thought current best practice was to use `SFSafariViewController` so that you don't bounce the user out of your app into Safari and back to your app.  I use the p2.oauth library in one of my apps that authenticates against Office365.  It uses `SFSafariViewController` and the process is pretty smooth.

Comment: Yes you're right! (AppAuth-iOS uses SFSafariViewController)

So the only question is, is a browser based flow also necessary for devices/apps that are in our "control" (MDM managed). Or is it safe in this case to implement a native login flow (user enters credentials directly into the app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an RFC about [OAuth2 for native apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252). It's worth reading - it discusses possible implementations and security risks involved. The general recommended way is to use the authorization code flow in a browser (not an internal application component), because this way the application cannot get the user credentials. People use to trust the browser and the authentication provider more than other apps, so the visibility of URL and the verified SSL certificate is important too.

The RFC covers also the [iOS implementation details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#page-18):

> Apps can initiate an authorization request in the browser, without the
> user leaving the app, through the "SFSafariViewController" class or
> its successor "SFAuthenticationSession", which implement the in- app
> browser tab pattern.  Safari can be used to handle requests on old
> versions of iOS without in-app browser tab functionality.

So if you use the `SFAuthenticationSession` you don't need to open a new Safari window and the user experience should not suffer.

If you use the [Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37) (users enter their credentials into your application directly), you will make it less secure for the same reasons - the credentials get exposed to the application. And using this grant, you cannot use the third party authentication providers in Keycloak (Google, Facebook).

It's up to you (and your organization) how much secure you want the system to be, so you can opt for some compromises, but I would rather stick to the current best practices, since the app may grow later the compromises may turn to problems.